# Java, Strategy Pattern, Generics and return type

Tags: java, generics

I'm implementing the Strategy Pattern:

```
public interface Stuff<T> {
  T getStuff();
}

public class IntegerStuff implements Stuff<Integer> {
  public Integer getStuff() { .. }
}

public class StringStuff implements Stuff<String> {
   public String getStuff() { .. }
}
```

Now, I want to use a "Context" to set the strategy and execute the strategy method:

```
public class Context() {
   private Stuff stuff;
   public setStrategy(Stuff stuff) { this.stuff = stuff; }

   public Object doStuff() { // ARGH!
      return stuff.getStuff()
   }
}
```

How can I use generic, so that the type of the `doStuff()` method on the Context class, can be of the same type as the used strategy?

Comment: The strategy pattern allows a kind of black box behavior. You have a defined input and a defined output but what happened in between decides the strategy (which should be interchangeable). As you want to change the output of your method I think that strategy pattern is not the right choice here

Comment: @CRC, yeah, I think you are right, changing return type modifies the "contract"

Comment: Maybe this can be solved in another way: What are you trying to do with all this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to parameterize `Context` as well:

```
public class Context<T> {
   private Stuff<T> stuff;
   public setStrategy(Stuff<T> stuff) { this.stuff = stuff; }

   public T doStuff() { // ARGH!
      return stuff.getStuff()
   }
}
```

Comment: In this case (Strategy pattern), this doesn't work. 
I don't want to have to create a context with the type of the strategy class!

`Context<String> c = new Context<>();`

Comment: @Luciano: What does "this doesn't work" mean?  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: In this case you don't know your output type. So you can only be sure that the returned value is an object but nothing else. Therefore you can decide if you want to restrict your output or use Object as return type

Comment: As @CRC says, you either want to know the type from an outside caller, or you don't.  If you don't, you would still want to take and store a `Stuff<?>` instead of the raw type `Stuff`.

Comment: @MarkPeters He wants to change its strategy while runtime. But when he changes from IntegerStuff to StringStuff the generic will forbid it.

Comment: @MarkPeters sorry, I was editing my reply and hit the Enter key by mistake

Comment: From an agnostic outside consumer, the current runtime strategy is encapsulated right?  So given a `Context`, how could a consumer ever hope to safely know, and therefore care, whether it's acting as a string-producing context or an integer-producing context at compile time?  And if you don't care at compile time, generics is not the solution you're looking for.  But still, the return type being Object vs String/Integer *also* really only has compile-time utility, so still not sure what you're trying to accomplish.