# Java Generics : Converting methods to a single method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, generics, interface

In my Spring Boot app, I have the following methods:

```
public class ContainsIntegerFilter implements CsvToBeanFilter {

    private final int index;
    private final List<Integer> values; // list types are different (Integer)

    public boolean allowLine(String[] line) {
        return values.contains(Integer.parseInt(line[index]));
    }
}
```

```
public class ContainsStringFilter implements CsvToBeanFilter {

    private final int index;
    private final List<String> values; // list types are different (String)

    public boolean allowLine(String[] line) {
        return values.contains(line[index]);
    }
}
```

And calling these methods like this:

```
final CsvToBeanFilter filter = new ContainsIntegerFilter(0, idList);
```

I want to merge these methods into a single method using generics. But I am not sure if the following approach is the most proper way? Or should I use an interface and call that interface instead of the merged method:

```
public abstract class ContainsFilter<T> implements CsvToBeanFilter {

    private final int index;
    private final List<T> values;

    public boolean allowLine(T[] line) {
        return values.contains(line[index]);
    }
}
```

So, how can achieve this?

Comment: A downvoter does not get a notification that a comment has been added to a question they downvoted. The odds they see your comment are therefore effectively zilch.

Comment: And what about your answer? Maybe someone else does not like it or does like. If you are so sure that it is a good answer, why do not you post it?

Comment: Seems like a strategy pattern situation. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168724/java-strategy-pattern-generics-and-return-type

Comment: @rick Thanks a lot for reply. I tried it but cannot applied properly, maybe it is due to implementing CsvToBeanFilter. Do you have any idea about the usage that approach for my scenario? Any example answer please?

Answer (score 0):

In first approach, you are always passing String[] array as method arguments (both for string and int).

In second approach, you are passing T[] array which will change based on type T.

If you pass can String[] array in one case & Integer[] array in another as method arguments, you can use first one. That keeps code clean.

Update:
Sample code for second approach:

```
public class ContainsFilter<T> {

    private final int index = 1;
    private List<? extends Object> values1 = List.of("test1", "test2");
    private List<? extends Object> values2 = List.of(1, 2);
    

    public void allowLine(T[] line) {
        System.out.println(values1.contains(line[index]));
        System.out.println(values2.contains(line[index]));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] line1 = new String[] {"test111", "test2"};
        Integer[] line2 = new Integer[] {1, 2};
        ContainsFilter<String> c1 = new ContainsFilter<String>();
        c1.allowLine(line1);
        ContainsFilter<Integer> c2 = new ContainsFilter<Integer>();
        
        c2.allowLine(line2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @rzwitserloot Why did you vote down for each question and answer? Do you have any problem with SO?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the code is not working. Do you have any example for this scenario?

Comment: Rubita I think you suggest only using first method without generic, right? Any idea about converting to generic method?

Comment: By the way I voted up for your helps.

Comment: thank you. i have added some code for generics. it complies & works. "values" needs to be defined as <? extends Object> to make it work. It is to personal choice which one you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I tried, but the problem in here, I have to implement methods in the container class from `CsvToBeanFilter` and I have to add default `public boolean allowLine(String[] line) {}` method. But when I add it, the code hits only this method rather than my generic `allowLine` method. So, do you have an idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Any idea about that?